# How to use image as title and change the color of the text in html

Tags: html

My background is black, so I want to make the text white. Currently I have a code, but it's not working. I also want to insert a pic, but it's still not working.

```
<title color="white">This is title</title>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title tag is a mandatory html tag that defines the title of the document. You do not change the color or add pictures,
[more info here.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp)

**How to format text in html:**

if you are trying to add text to your page and it's not showing try changing the color of the text, for example:

```
<h1 style="color:white"> Title Here</h1>
```

**How to add picture in html:**

`<img src ="address to image"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** set the color of the  `<title>` tag as it specifies the text displayed as *the name of the page* in Google/Bing/Yandex search results and in your browser's title. You **cannot** add any images as well.

Here you are some [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_title.asp) on this tag.

I can guess, you want something like `<h1>Title</h1>`.

Comment: But my background it black, how to change the color of the title?

Comment: @SongTianyang, you misunderstand the meaning of the `<title>` tag. Wait, I'll edit my answer.